# mongoose findOneAndUpdate returns null for both err and doc (using Jest)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jestjs

I'm using Mongoose's findOneAndUpdate method, and can't seem to get any useful information back from it. I've tried using the Query that comes back from calling it (in `updatedUser`), but it returns `null`; I've also tried including the callback argument, but when I do that I get `null` back for both `err` and `doc`.

Context: I'm using Jest to build a test suite, and writing a test for this function. I have had the function working in my application outside of the test suite, and while I have changed parts of the function I haven't changed anything in the findOneAndUpdate call, except for adding the callback argument.

Expected behavior:
Either 'err' or 'doc' doesn't return null so I at least know what's happening.

I've worked with Mocha and I'm learning Jest, and I've discovered a couple of other entertaining things that Jest does. I know from experience that this is most likely me missing something fairly obvious, but I'd love to be able to blame something else for once. :)

updateUser.js:

```
const updateUser = async (user) => {

  console.log('user in updater:', user);

  const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: user._id },
    {
      $set: {
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password,
        ageRange: user.ageRange,
        gender: user.gender,

        accountCreatedAt: user.accountCreateAt,
        meetingPlaces: user.meetingPlaces,
        flags: user.flags,
        tokens: user.tokens,
      }
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, doc) => {
      console.log(err, doc);
    }
  );

  //placeholders until I get some kind of usable response from findOneAndUpdate
  return {err: false, res: 'cat'};
};
```

terminal output:

```
 console.log server/db/crud_Users/updateUser.js:8
   user in updater: { _id: 5b1aa9a146b59048dd86dbc2,
     name: 'test',
     email: '24479981326297030000@test.com',
     password: 'testtest',
     ageRange: '1',
     gender: 'Female',
     accountCreatedAt: '2018-06-08T11:06:57-05:00',
     meetingPlaces: [],
     flags: [],
     tokens: [],
     homeLocations: [],
     hostedEvents: [],
     attendingEvents: [],
     __v: 0 }

 console.log server/db/crud_Users/updateUser.js:28
   null null

 console.log server/db/crud_Users/updateUser.js:32
    updatedUser: null
```

Comment: Maybe both err and doc are null because you have no error and there is no document in your collection that matches the `_id = user. _id` so your `findOneAndUpdate` returns nothing (which means null)

Comment: @Bentaiba I thought that too, but shouldn't it return something in `err` if there is no document? If not, what does show up in `err`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thank you for explaining the issue that well.
It is mentioned in the official documentation of MongoDB [here](http://www.mongoing.com/docs/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate.html) that `findOneAndUpdate` updates the first document in the collection that matches the request and return the original document.

I supposed that both `err` and `doc` are null because of the document that you want to update doesn't exist in your collection. It is not mentioned in the documentation what is the behavior of `findOneAndUpdate` if there is no document that matches the query. So, I tried to go deeper into it.

I saw in the documentation (you can learn more about it [here](http://www.mongoing.com/docs/reference/method/db.collection.update.html#upsert-behavior)) that if the parameter `upsert` isn't mentioned, it will take `false` as a default value. And I saw here in the P.S. part that if `upsert` is `false` and the document doesn't exist, than `doc` will be `null`.

Comment: You are right. After I put my answer up I worked at it a little more and came to this conclusion as well but forgot to update my answer.  I found that I had to write my own error handling (`if doc = null //return a custom error message`). I ended up rewriting it using Promises, so now it looks like this (sorry for poor formatting): 
 `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {$set: userWithChanges}, { new: true }).then((res) => {
      resolve({ err: null, res });
    }).catch((err) => resolve({ err, res: null }));
  });`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: not correct - see other answer. I got it figured out. I was returning the variable asynchronously before it had a value, so it wasn't a `findOneAndUpdate` issue after all. :/

Comment: I really don't think this is the right answer. If `findOneAndUpdate` doesn't find any document that matches your request, doesn't mean that it's an error. `err` is null because there is no error in the execution of the request. It's true that your code is asynchronous, but you're using callbacks, so the given `err` and `doc` is exactly what it should be returned. Can you please ensure that the document exists in your collection and try to update it with the same code and see?

Comment: you can see here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate that if you use callbacks, you will get the results immediately.